# Relatively prime check?

Tags: c, math, greatest-common-divisor

Ok so relatively prime means that two numbers have no common factors greater than 1. It can also be viewed as two numbers that have gcd = 1.

So along those lines, this is the code i wrote to find two relatively prime numbers e,z :

```
for(e = 0,flag=0; (flag==1); e++){ 
    if( gcd( e, z ) == 1){   // z in this example is 60
        flag = 1;
    } 
}

printf("e = %d\n",e);
```

and the gcd function is defined as :

```
int gcd(int i, int x){
   if(x % i == 0) return( i );
   return( gcd( x % i, x ) );
}
```

when I set `z = 60`, the e I get is `e= 0`  ... Actually I keep getting the same **e** with which I initialize the for loop

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way of finding if two numbers are relatively prime?

**EDIT:**

Ok as per the suggestion from minitech here is the modified code:

```
for(e = 2,flag=0; !flag; e++){
    if( gcd( e, z ) == 1){
        flag = 1;
    } 
}
```

now when I set my z=60 , my e is coming out to be e = 60 which is again wrong. Correct answer should be e = 7

Comment: Your `gcd` function is not robust, it does a division by zero if called with `i = 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You shouldn’t start at zero
- Your `flag` condition should be `!flag`

After fixing that, you will always get 1, because it’s relatively prime to everything. Try starting at `z - 1` and decrementing if you want the biggest one. You should also just `break;` instead of keeping a flag.

Comment: I modieifed the code as per your suggestions ( see the edit ) .. but now i get e = 60. Which is again wrong . Correct e should be 7

Comment: @sukhvir: Euclid’s GCD algorithm looks like `int gcd(int a, int b) { if(!b) return a; return gcd(b, a % b); }`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little fragile, since it can't handle a zero argument; e.g.,

`gcd(z, z) = gcd(z, 0) = gcd(0, z) = |z|.`

I'd go with something like:

```
unsigned gcd (unsigned u, unsigned v)
{
    unsigned t;
    for (; (t = v) != 0; u = t)
        v = u % v;
    return u;
}
```

I use unsigned types, because there's no reason to use negative arguments - they don't affect the result of a gcd, which is always non-negative.